# Can a summed ordinal Likert scale be considered a scale variable?

Tags: ordinal-data, likert

I have a 16-item questionnaire that measures responses on a 5 point Likert scale from 1 = none of the time, 3 = some of the time, 5 = all of the time.

I define each item as an ordinal variable; however the 16 items can be summed together to form a total score or several subscale.

is this total score still an ordinal variable or is it now considered a scale variable?